# How I can get out from the 'git log' command process it and continue with other commands?

Tags: git, git-log

When I call a `git log` I get some like the following, but I can't continue because end blocks my actions.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Q</kbd> in this case (`q` is **quit**).

Answer (score 0):

`git log | cat`

You might want to add some options to the git command, or you'll be scrolling through allll the commits.

Also,

`git log > file.txt`

Options may not be necessary (or desired) if you write it to a file.